# how to make counsel-locate respect my cwd

Tags: counsel, swiper

Emacs has a concept of "current directory",
shown by doing

```
M-x pwd
```

I can change to specific directory by doing `M-x cd`

I recently installed swiper/counsel/ivy, to make searching easier.
Since the `locate` command is not that great on MacOS, I added this bit

```
(setq locate-command "mdfind")
(setq counsel-locate-cmd 'counsel-locate-cmd-mdfind)
```

My issue is this. Let's say I `cd`  to `/folder1/`, and then 
I invoke `M-x counsel-locate` and start typing

```
id rsa
```

I am shown `id_rsa.pub` files from other folders, for example `/folder2/id_rsa.pub`. I was expecting `counsel-locate` to respect my "current directory" when doing its recursive search.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By default spotlight searches the entire disk. mdfind has a parameter -onlyin to limit searches to a specific folder. It may be worth submitting an issue to the ivy github repo to make this available when using a universal argument.

Comment: It sounds like you want to find a file in a set of sub directories. I use projectile and its related counsel commands.